# UE4 Blueprint OnActorBeginOverlap not working

Tags: unreal-4

I am following the tutorial [here](https://www.unrealengine.com/blog/blueprint-basics) entitled "Making a Pickup". I have created a Blueprint class from the Statue SM:

[image]

I have set the SM Collision Preset to OverlapAll per the instructions. In the Event Graph I have the following:

[image]

When I run the simulation and run into the statue, nothing happens. If I monitor the Blueprint I see no triggering. I have wired the everything to trigger from EventBeginPlay and it all works as expected, but the ActorBeginOverlap node never triggers.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found it, I need to have the Generate Overlap Events box checked in the Collision pane:

[image]

Comment: This should be on by default.